# A group generated by all the root subgroups above ideal of $\mathbb Z[\alpha]$ is of finite index in $G(\mathbb Z[\alpha])$

Tags: algebraic-groups, root-systems, arithmetic-groups, chevalley-groups

Let $G$ be a simply connected complex Chevalley group and let $T$ be some maximal torus in $G$ with $\dim T\geq 2$.

From *"A note on generators for arithmetic subgroups of algebraic groups"* by Raghunathan, we have that for every ideal $I\lhd\mathbb Z$, $$\Gamma(I):=\langle U_\phi(I)|\phi\in\Phi \rangle$$ is of finite index in $G(\mathbb Z)$.

> Is it also true for every ideal $I\lhd\mathbb Z[\alpha]$ that $Γ(I)$ of finite index in $G(\mathbb Z[\alpha])$?

Specifically, I'm looking at $G=SL_n$

Where:

- $\Phi$ denote the root system of $G$ with respect to $T$;
- $U_\phi$ is the root subgroup corresponding to $\phi\in\Phi$;
- $\alpha$ is an element that is integral over $\mathbb Z$;
- if $I$ is an ideal of the ring $A$ and $H\leq G$ we mark $H(I):=\{x\in H(A)|x\equiv1(\mathrm{mod}\,I)\}$ where $H(A):=H\cap \mathrm{GL}_n(A)$.

Comment: where in Raghunathan's paper, do you see the  statement for $G({\mathbb Z})$?

Comment: I believe in page *365* *(Theorem 1.2)*. He uses in the paper the ring of S-integers in $k$, I don't think I understand it enough but from what I gather for $k=\mathbb Q$ we can get $Λ=\mathbb Z$.

Comment: If he uses the ring of S integers in the number field k, then that answers your question; in any case, the answer to your question is indeed yes; that is what is proved in Raghunathan's paper.  Not just the special case of $\mathbb Z$.

Comment: The reason is that $G({\mathbb Z}[\alpha ])$ is commensurate to $G(O_k)$ where $k$ is the field over $\mathbb Q$ generated by $\alpha$; every non-zero ideal $I$ of ${\mathbb Z}[\alpha]$ contains a nonzero  ideal $J$ of $O_k$; thus Raghunathan's theorem applied to $O_k$ and $J$ gives what you want.

Comment: Thank you very much, can you please refer to a source regarding the ideal property you mentions?

Comment: $I\subset {\mathbb Z}[\alpha]$ has finite index in $O_k$. Hence $J$ contains $I=NO_k$ for some non-zero integer $N$ since $O_k$ is a finitely generated torsion free abelian group. Now $I$ is a nonzero ideal

Comment: you meant $I$ contains $J=NO_k$ ?

Comment: Yes. I meant to write $I\subset {\mathbb Z}[\alpha]$ contains $J=NO-k$.